# Synchronization in Constructors to make it Happens-before

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

I have a question about how to make an object guaranteed to be thread-safe by the Java Memory Model.

I have read a lot which say that writing a synchronized scope in a constructor does not make sense, but why doesn't it? Yes, it is true that as long as the object under construction is not shared among threads (, which it shouldn't be), no threads other than the constructing one can reach any synchronized(this){...}, so there are no need to make that scope in the constructor in order to exclude them. But synchronized scopes are not only for exclusion; they are also used to create happens-before relationships. [JLS.17.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4)

Here is a sample code to make my point clear.

```
public class Counter{

    private int count;

    public Counter(int init_value){
        //synchronized(this){
            this.count = init_value;
        //}
    }

    public synchronized int getValue(){
        return count;
    }

    public synchronized void addValue(){
        count++;
    }
}
```

Think about the case where a thread t0 creates a Counter object and another thread t1 uses it. If there were the synchronized statement in the constructor, it would obviously be guaranteed to be thread-safe. (Since all actions in synchronized scopes have a happens-before relationship with each other.) But if not, i.e. no synchronized statement, does the Java Memory Model still guarantee that the initializing write by t0 of count can be seen by t1? I think not. It is just like f.y can see 0 in the sample code 17.5-1 in [JLS.17.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5). Unlike the case of JSL.17.5-1, now the second thread accesses the field only from synchronized methods, but I think synchronized statements have no guaranteed effect in this situation. (They don't create any happens-before relationship with any action by t0.) Some say that the rule about a happens-before edge at the end of a constructor guarantees it, but the rule seems to be just saying a constructor happens-before finalize().

Then should I write the synchronized statement in the constructor to make the object thread-safe? Or are there some rules or logics about the Java Memory Model I have missed and actually no need for that? If I am true, even Hashtable of openjdk (though i know it is obsolete) seems not to be thread-safe.

Or am I wrong about the definition of being thread-safe and about the policy for concurrency? If I transfer that Counter object from t0 to t1 by a thread-safe way, e.g. through a volatile variable, there seems to be no problem. (In that case, the construction by t0 happens-before the volatile write, which happens-before the volatile read by t1, which happens-before everything t1 does to it.) Should I always transfer even thread-safe objects (but not immutable) among threads through a way that causes a happens-before relationship?

Comment: "Think about the case where a thread t0 creates a Counter object and another thread t1 uses it." How will t1 have a reference to `Counter` before the constructor returns on t0?

Comment: Your problem is solved by safe publication.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the object is safely published (for instance, by instantiating it as `someVolatileField = new Foo()`), then you don't need synchronization in the constructor. If it's not, then synchronization in the constructor is not enough.

There was a somewhat lengthy discussion on the java concurrency-interest list [a few years back](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2011-December/008591.html) about this; I'll provide the summary here. (Full disclosure: I started that discussion, and was involved throughout it.)

Remember that the happens-before edge only applies between one thread releasing the lock, and a subsequent thread acquiring it. So, let's say you have:

```
someNonVolatileField = new Foo();
```

There are are three significant sets of actions here:

1. the object being allocated, with all its fields set to 0/null
2. the constructor running, which includes an acquire and release of the object's monitor
3. the object's reference being assigned to `someNonVolatileField`

Let's say another thread then uses the reference, and calls a `synchronized doFoo()` method. Now we add two more actions:

4. reading the `someNonVolatileField` reference
5. invoking `doFoo()`, which includes an acquire and release of the object's monitor

Since the publication to someNonVolatileField wasn't safe, there is a lot of reordering that the system can do. In particular, the reading thread is allowed to see things happening in this order:

1. the object being allocated, with all its fields set to 0/null
2. the object's reference being assigned to `someNonVolatileField`
3. reading the `someNonVolatileField` reference
4. invoking `doFoo()`, which includes an acquire and release of the object's monitor
5. the constructor running, which includes an acquire and release of the object's monitor

In this case, there's still a happens-before edge, but goes the other way around from what you want. Specifically, the call to `doFoo()` formally happens-before the constructor.

This does buy you a *little* bit; it means that any synchronized method (or block) is guaranteed to see either the full effects of the constructor, or none of those effects; it won't see only part of the constructor. But in practice, you probably want to guarantee that you see the effects of the constructor; that's why you wrote the constructor, after all.

You can get around this by having doFoo() not be synchronized, and instead set up some spin-loop waiting for a flag that says the constructor has run, followed by a manual `synchronized(this)` block. But by the time you get to that level of complexity, it's probably better to just say "this object is thread safe *assuming* its initial publication was safe." That's the de-facto assumption for most mutable classes that bill themselves as thread-safe; immutable ones can use `final` fields, which is thread-safe even in the face of unsafe publication, but which doesn't require explicit synchronization.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Assuming JVM 1.5+, there's a full happens-before edge between the first thread writing to the reference and any subsequent thread reading from it.

Comment: An aside question. Can the `synchronized(this)` be elided away, in theory, since `this` doesn't seem to escape?

Comment: @RealSkeptic If A happens-before B, then a thread that sees B must see A _and_ all of the actions that preceded A (can't look the exact jls ref right now, sorry... somewhere in chapter 17. :) ). So in this case, the read would see the write to the reference, as well as all of the actions that came before it in that writing thread -- and specifically, the `new` call and the constructor.

Comment: @JohnVint `this` can't be elided, since that reference could very well be accessed by another thread. Remember that the synchronization is on the reference itself, not on the variable that happens to hold it. The same reference that `this` refers to might be accessed in another thread, via the `someNonVolatileField` variable.

Comment: @RealSkeptic the logic is as follows: in a single thread all wires in the construvtor happen before the write to the field. If another thread can see the updated field it must also see all writes that happened before the write to the field.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, the key is that the _happens before_ relationship is _transitive_.  If you know that A happens before B, and you know that B happens before C, then you can safely assume that A happens before C.  Anything (including updates and accesses to non-volatile fields) that happens within a single thread must appear to happen in _program order_.  So, if thread A updates some non-volatile field f, and then updates a volatile field v, and then thread B accesses the new value that was written to v, thread B _must_ subsequently be able to see the new value of f as well.

Comment: @yshavit , you are saying when a thread reads a value that another thread has written, the write happens-before the read? I doubt there exists such a rule in JSL.17 and I think it is true only when the field is volatile. And I guess your theory does not explain the fact that in the example code JSL.17.5-1, a thread can see the uninitialized value of f.y though it obviously has seen what f is.

Comment: @JumpingBeans Sorry, to clarify, I meant that only in the case of a write/read to volatile fields.

Comment: I don't understand how this answer, while it may contain accurate information, addresses the original question. The field being protected in the original question is an `int`, not an object reference, so this answer is not relevant, and the point being made in the original question is still valid and yet to be refuted. What am I missing?

Comment: @Archie The field being protected was the `int`, but the reference that the OP proposed for doing the protection (in their commented-out lines) was `this`. The tldr is that if you did that, another thread that gets that reference through unsafe publication could validly read `count == 0`, with that read being ordered _before_ the synchronized block in the constructor. That almost definitely defeats the intent behind that synchronized block.

Comment: Thanks. Here's another post that talks about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299543/java-non-final-ints-visible-after-construction